# Git Pull and Clone From HostGator Fails

Tags: git, ssh

I'm working a small drupal site, and I'm trying to pull and push changes from my local Windows box to a remote shared hosting account on HostGator (linux). I have installed the git bash on my machine, and setup passwordless login within the Git Bash. That seems to work fine.

Here's my command:

```
git clone "ssh://user@domain.com/~/public_html/.git"
```

Here's the complete response:

```
Cloning into public_html...
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
remote: Counting objects: 3330, done.fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible     repository corruption on the remote side.

remote: fatal: unable to create thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
ssh domain.com
Last login: Mon Jan 23 14:38:07 2012 from xxxx
[user@domain.com]$ cd public_html
[user@domain.com]$ git fsck
[user@domain.com]$
```

I've also tried deleting the local and remote git repos, doing another git init and commiting everything fresh. I still get the same error when trying to clone the repo to my machine.

Why can't I clone (or pull) from the remote site? How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

StackExchange eventually taught me that git ran out of memory.  (sorry I lost the original answer!). I was able it to fix the error by sshing to the remote machine and running these commands:

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m"
git config --global pack.SizeLimit "100m"
git config --global pack.threads "1"
```

This does seem to slow down git, but at least it works on my shared hosting account! I think that the key is the threads bit, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to take a loot at [url1](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-clone-path-or-ssh-problem-with-git-upload-pack-in-1-6-0-td1079095.html) and [url2](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/corrupted-repository-td1132584.html)

Comment: Thanks vpatil! I'm having hard time digging through these threads, but I'm not sure that's my problem. I found my answer somewhere else on stack exchange and I'm posting it below.